# How would one modify the total number of available talents a character has in Azerothcore?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

So I'm trying to make a server where my friends can log on, hit 80, and then have *above* the normal 71 talent points at level 80. I can't seem how to figure out how to implement this, is there a SQL table that holds this information that I can directly update, or is there a better  less direct way to change it?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the World.conf file, to add more talentpoints as players level up.
Look for the

```
#
#    Rate.Talent
#        Description: Talent point rate.
#        Default:     1
```

and set it to e.g. 3. This will produce 3 talents points pr level up

Comment: Hi, the problem with editing the World.conf file is that you're locked into multiples of the max number of talent points. So for example, in WOTLK you get 71 max talent points natively, and with your method I could get 142, or 213 maximum talent points, but what if I wanted 101? I figured out how to do that! <br> So if you navigate to the Player.cpp file, there's a const called uint32 Player::CalculateTalentPoints(). This is where you need to make changes to get more granular control over max talent points.

Comment: maybe you can use GM command .modify talentpoints 101